# Scaling and keeping proportions

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to learn HTML/CSS and working on a nav bar, however, I am experiencing a scaling problem. This is the website in full screen.[image: Fullscreen image]

This is the website minimized a bit.
[image: Minimized a bit]

Then this is the website minimized all the way.
[image: Minimized a bit]

As you can tell when I scale the website around into different scales then the proportions mess up and things begin to overlap. I have tried making the children absolute while keeping the containers relative. I am also using em's for measurement and not using pixels. What can I do to keep everything proportional while scaling?

This is the js fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/2w1r136j/2/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <nav>
      <img class="logo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8a/Westworld_Logo.svg/2000px-Westworld_Logo.svg.png" alt="logo">
      <div class="leftNavContainer">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Story</a>
      </div>
      <div class="rightNavContainer">
        <a href="#">Characters</a>
        <a href="#">Create</a>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #222;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

header {
  background: white;
  height: 3.5em;
}

.logo {
  height: 4.5em;
  width: 4.5em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px !important;  /* 50% of your logo width */
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.leftNavContainer {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
}

.leftNavContainer a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 2em;
  margin-left: 2em;
}

.rightNavContainer {
  float: right;
}

.rightNavContainer a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 2em;
  margin-left: 2em;
}
```

Comment: You could use media queries within which you selectively change the css for elements. Check out https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well Media queries might work, but a much better implementation would be using Flexbox or better CSS Grid. 
I've updated the fiddle with a flexbox implementation.

https://jsfiddle.net/khpv2azq/3/

HTML

```
<head>
  <title>
    Westworld
  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <nav>
      <div class="leftNavContainer">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Story</a>
      </div>
       <img class="logo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8a/Westworld_Logo.svg/2000px-Westworld_Logo.svg.png" alt="logo">
      <div class="rightNavContainer">
        <a href="#">Characters</a>
        <a href="#">Create</a>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #222;
  font-size: 1em;
}

nav{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

header {
  background: white;
  height: 3.5em;
}

.logo {
  height: 4.5em;
  width: 4.5em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px !important;
  /* 50% of your logo width */
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.leftNavContainer {

}

.leftNavContainer a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  margin: 4px;
}

.rightNavContainer {

}

.rightNavContainer a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

Also MDN resource for Flex box -

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

Hope this help!

Comment: Thank you Shobhit. I just have one question you did reduce the margin from 70px to 4px. I wanted to keep the space between the elements around 70px. Is there a way to keep those elements around 70px. I changed it back to 70px but now when I scale the elements end up stacking on one other. I did try putting flex-wrap: nowrap;

Comment: Hi Jack,
Ideally the spacing should be given in proportions ( something like % ). If you want to have fixed margin in px , then probably you need to add some media query for screen sizes.

Comment: Thank You I did not know that spacing should be given in %'s.

Answer (score 1):

You can use media queries to change sizes at breakpoints
ex:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
        font-size: .7em;

    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2w1r136j/7/

However, you might consider using the media queries to incorporate a responsive design which will work for mobile. 
A common idiom is to collapse the menu items into full width elements, and to bump up the font size.

something like: https://jsfiddle.net/2w1r136j/40/